# Particle system doesn't render but shows in 3D view

Tags: particles

Not sure where I am going wrong. The render setting is turned on for the particle system, but it still doesn't work when I render the animation. I'm sure it's something straight forward, but I can't find out which setting isn't correct. Where would be the next place to look? It's just a simple piece of text with a particle system. Thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx4hiqssrlcrj9j/myFanArt.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object with a material and shape you want for the particles and assign that to the particle's Dupli Object section.

[image]

I added a green sphere on a different layer and selected it as the particle's shape.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I was scratching my head for hours over that! it makes more sense now. Also didn't know about Blend-Exchange, that's really handy. I actually set up a dropbox just to post my question, lol! If only I'd known. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The particles Render Type is set to object, but there is no object assigned.